# Azure CI/CD for multiple solutions in same project

Tags: c#, azure, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to implement CI/CD using Azure Devops... there are multiple projects in the same solution(local machine)eg: several web projects,angular project with .net core etc

Should i create separate projects in Azure or push them all under a single project by creating a repo in the root directory;i will need to define the build and release pipelines for CI/CD

[image]

please advice

Comment: Start by creating a monolithic repository and set up CI/CD for it. If, later, you have a need to develop/deploy individual components, split those out one-by-one.

Comment: @AndreasHassing okay.. thanks